# how to count Google Buzz followers

Tags: jquery, google-buzz

How can I get a user's Google Buzz follower count? Can I use jQuery or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if all you want is buzz follower count, you don't even need jQuery.  Just use the [JSONP](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/getting_started.html#JSONP) support in the Buzz API, and call the [followers endpoint](http://code.google.com/apis/buzz/v1/using_rest.html#people-followers)...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function followerCount(response) {
        alert(response.data.totalResults);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/people/googlebuzz/@groups/@followers?alt=json&callback=followerCount&max-results=0"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```